# GeoServer: Unable to publish a PostGIS table successfully via REST or WebUI

Tags: rest, workspace, geoserver-cloud

I have a GeoServer Version 2.21-CLOUD. Data is a RDS instance flowing through JDBCStore.

Tring to publish a Layer using a REST interface, but I keep getting the below error :

> /workspaces/gis-data-store/datastores/gis-postgres/featuretypes: Cannot invoke "org.geoserver.catalog.NamespaceInfo.getURI()" because the return value of "org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ResourceInfoImpl.getNamespace()" is null

Strange part is, when the workspace is made, I don't see any Namespace under this http://localhost:8085/geoserver-cloud/rest/namespaces

But I can see the same workspace fine under here.
http://localhost:8085/geoserver-cloud/rest/workspaces

Anyone know the reason behind REST interface not able to create a namespace for the workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Configmap pwd was not set, its working fine after changing default_pass to correct pwd .

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  rabbitmq.conf: |-
    ## Username and password
    ##
    default_user = geoserver
    default_pass = CHANGEME
```